# Mock Action Delegate Property

Tags: c#, unit-testing, delegates, moq

Consider the following code segment:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    Action<string> MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public Action<string> MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyClass.MyProperty += s => DoSomething("");
```

Test:

```
_mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Default);

_myClassMock = __mockRepository.Create<IMyClass>();

_myClassMock.Setup(x => x.MyProperty).Returns(It.IsAny<Action<string>>());
```

If mock behavior is set to strict

```
_mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

Setup does not apply

Comment: Please, share the `IMyClass` interface

Comment: also, what do you mean _Setup does not apply_ Is your test failed or you get an error? Have you subscribed to the `Action`?

Comment: Test runs fine but fails when it executes the line in the usage heading